# SQL update questions

Tags: sql

Table Name : Hist_table

```
 Shp_cd wt_grp  net_wt  tot_wt
   101   10       9      7
   102   20       8      2
   103   15       4      1
```

Factor_table

```
Fact_id fact_column factor
  1     wt_grp        2
  2     net_wt        5
  3     tot_wt        3
```

Note – this factor table contains rows as the column name of hist_table.

Now we have to update the Hist_table with the multiplied with the factors

For example wt_grp factor is 2 then we have to update all the wt_grp column of hist table as 
Hist_table.wt_grp * factor_table.factor

So the result should be

```
shpcd   wt_grp  net_wt  tot_wt
101     20        45    21
102     40        40    6
103     30        20    3
```

Please let me know the query to update this

Comment: I think either your multiplication is wrong or your calculations. Every time you are multiplying it with 2 while the result should be 20, 100, 45.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai, the calculation is fine: as I read the requirements, each column has a specific multiplier associated with it.  Wt_grp is always 2, net_wt is always 5, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to perform a CROSS JOIN between the two tables (resulting in a Cartesian Product), and then selectively apply the calculations you want.

That resultset can then be reduced to a single row per shpcd using `MAX()`

```
-- sample data
    DECLARE @Hist TABLE (Shp_cd int, wt_grp int, net_wt int, tot_wt int)
    INSERT INTO @Hist (Shp_cd, wt_grp, net_wt, tot_wt) VALUES (101, 10, 9, 7)
    INSERT INTO @Hist (Shp_cd, wt_grp, net_wt, tot_wt) VALUES (102, 20, 8, 2)
    INSERT INTO @Hist (Shp_cd, wt_grp, net_wt, tot_wt) VALUES (103, 15, 4, 1)

    DECLARE @Factor TABLE (Fact_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), fact_column varchar(6), factor int)
    INSERT INTO @Factor (fact_column, factor) VALUES ('wt_grp', 2)
    INSERT INTO @Factor (fact_column, factor) VALUES ('net_wt', 5)
    INSERT INTO @Factor (fact_column, factor) VALUES ('tot_wt', 3)

-- cross join to pick up factors
    SELECT 
        h.shp_cd,
        MAX(CASE WHEN f.fact_column = 'wt_grp' THEN wt_grp * factor END) AS wt_grp,
        MAX(CASE WHEN f.fact_column = 'net_wt' THEN net_wt * factor END) AS net_wt,
        MAX(CASE WHEN f.fact_column = 'tot_wt' THEN tot_wt * factor END) AS tot_wt
    FROM 
        @Hist h
         CROSS JOIN 
        @Factor f
    GROUP BY h.Shp_cd -- to bring it down to a single resultset
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following

```
-- update wt_grp
update h set h.wt_grp=h.wt_grp*f.factor
from Hist_table h,Factor_table f 
where f.fact_column='wt_grp'

-- update net_wt  
update h set h.net_wt=h.net_wt*f.factor
from Hist_table h,Factor_table f 
where f.fact_column='net_wt'

-- update tot_wt
update h set h.tot_wt=h.tot_wt*f.factor
from Hist_table h,Factor_table f 
where f.fact_column='tot_wt'


select * from Hist_table
```

here a working [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e8bf/1)

hope this will help you